# Create an Asset of HTTP-API Type in Anypoint Exchange using Exchange / Platform API?

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-platform, anypoint-exchange

How can I create an asset of http-api type in Anypoint exchange using the Platform / Exchange API ?

I am trying to automate the HTTP API Proxy generation in my build pipeline and since an HTTP API doesn't have a RAML, I am little lost on how to create the asset to exchange?

I am aware that there in an API that can take a JSON input for the creating exchange assets but I am unable to trace it correctly where there is no RAML for the asset.

Comment: Is the question about creating an asset in Anypoint Exchange, or to deploy a proxy? Those are two different questions.

Comment: Have you already read the detailed documentation page that explains the steps needed to publish an asset using the API? https://docs.mulesoft.com/exchange/exchange-api

Comment: The question is about creating an asset in Anypoint Exchange that does not have an associated RAML.

Answer (score 1):

The [step by step guide in the documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/exchange/exchange-api) plus the example linked on that page that points to the [asset creation API documentation portal](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/exchange-experience-api/minor/2.0/pages/Asset%20Creation/) has all the information that you need. There are examples for each type of asset, including HTTP API.

> HTTP API
>
> This example creates an asset of type HTTP.
>
> Increase the major version for each new version of an HTTP API. For
> example, increase from 1.0.0 to 2.0.0.
>
> Change these fields:
>
> ```
> organizationId
> groupId
> assetId
> version
> name
> description
> assetLink
> apiVersion
> ```
>
> Note: The type field is specified because it can not be inferred from
> a file classifier.
>
> ```
> curl -v \
>   -H 'Authorization: bearer ANYPOINT_TOKEN' \
>   -H 'x-sync-publication: true' \
>   -F 'name=http asset name' \
>   -F 'description=Description of the asset' \
>   -F 'type=http-api' \
>   -F 'properties.assetLink=http://www.my-http-api-url.com' \
>   -F 'properties.apiVersion=v3' \
> https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/api/v2/organizations/:organizationId/assets/:groupId/:assetId/:version
> ```